# How do I use RefersToRange?

Tags: vba, excel, range

Can anyone tell me how to use RefersToRange in vba? and what and when is the need of it.

Please provide with simple example first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, there is the concept of a **named range**, that is a range of cells which has a name attached to it. This is represented by the [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839264.aspx) object.

The [RefersToRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834918.aspx) method:

> Returns the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) object referred to by a Name object.

For example, let's say I want to read the values only in the print area of the current worksheet. I need the `Name` object in order to access the print area, but I can't do anything useful with it; if I want to do something useful I have to access the range of cells referred to by that name:

```
Dim n As Name
Set n = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Print_Area")
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = n.RefersToRange
Dim values() As Variant
values = rng 'I can't read values with a Name object, but I can with a Range object
```

Comment: i already checked msdn and its still unclear to me. That is why i posted here. Please provide your own example and explain what is happening. Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenBehera Updated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have discovered is that sometimes referring to a named range in this fashion:

ThisWorkbook.Range("DownloadPictures").Value = "yes"

results in:

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

But referring to the named range in this fashion:

ThisWorkbook.Names("DownloadPictures").RefersToRange = "yes"

works fine.  My particular circumstance is that the named range ("DownloadPictures") is scoped to the entire workbook, which has several worksheets. I am referring to the name in one of the worksheet's Worksheet_Calculate subroutines.  I don't understand why the first method causes an error and the second does not but apparently this is one reason to use the RefersToRange property.

Answer (score 0):

RefersToRange is, one of many ways, to 'point' a range. For example,

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("DownloadPictures").RefersToRange = "yes"
```

the above code, points to the range, which can be a cell, named "DownloadPictures" and sets it value to "yes". As a matter of fact, I'd rather use,

```
ThisWorkbook.range("DownloadPictures").Value = "yes"
```

The 'Name' in MS Excel is similar to the Variant variable type, but unlike the variables you 'Dim' in the VB code, the 'Name' only be used (or you can consider it is only be used) in the Workbook. The 'Name' and variables are not interfered with each other.

If you open the 'Name Manager', the concept becomes easier to understand. The Name can be created to refer to a cell, a range of cell (a range), some value (so called constant), or a formula.

> Each Name object represents a defined name for a range of cells. Names can be either built-in names—such as Database, Print_Area, and Auto_Open—or custom names. ---MSDN

As a Name can refer to range, constant or a formula `.RefersToRange` specifically refer to a range. And return false if not so.