# Get Named Range Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks that have a lot of the same named ranges and I need to move values from the second workbook to the first. I can do this by specifying which sheet the range is on and the name of range, but there are about 200 named ranges spread out over 20-something sheets and I only need the named ranges that are on 11 of those sheets. I could take the time to figure it out and hard code moving each one, but would really like it to be a mostly automated process. That way if a new range is added it can just be done automatically and I don't have to update the code.

The code I have so far is:

```vb
For Each Name In sheetList
    Set sheet2vals = sheet2.Sheets(Name).Range(rangename)
    Set sheet1vals = sheet1.Sheets(Name).Range(rangename)
    sheet2vals.Copy sheet1vals
Next Name
```

sheetList is an array of sheet names where all the ranges are stored. That part works exactly as I need it, I just need to find a way to pull the ranges from each of the sheets and move them. However, the only way I can seem to find to get the list of named ranges is by pulling at the Workbook level, which doesn't tell me what sheet it is on.

Comment: How do the 11 sheets (which are the targeted ones) differ from the others? You will have to set up a loop to automate this process. Therefor we need some conditions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459845/how-do-i-use-referstorange

Comment: Each `Name` has a `RefersToRange` property that gives you a `Range` object, and every `Range` has a `Parent` property that gives you the `Worksheet` it belongs to.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon this is exactly what I needed. If you want to move this to a response I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Name` has a `RefersToRange` property that gives you a `Range` object, and every `Range` has a `Parent` property that gives you the `Worksheet` it belongs to.

So if you have a `Name` object, you can always know what sheet it's referring to.